# AWS: Can't connect EC2 instance to RDS instance after configuring security groups

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After starting up a MySql RDS t2.micro instance and configuring the security groups accordingly to grant access from both my own ip and the public ip of my EC2 instance I received a connection timeout when trying to connect. The connection works perfectly fine locally, Multi AZ is set to None and the regions on both the RDS and EC2 are exactly the same.

There is probably something small I'm missing but I've read through countless documentation now trying to find out what it is.

[image: One configured to grant local access and the other for EC2]

Comment: Can you post your security group configuration?  Main thing is what ports are open on the RDS instance.  You can also validate you can telnet from your EC2 instance to the RDS instance on the port that you assume is open.

Comment: @GradyGCooper See edit, thanks.

Comment: I'd allow acces from the security group assigned to your ec2 instance rather than its public ip (and if you did insist on using ip, then it would be using the private ip normally)

Comment: You may want to follow this documentation, if you haven't: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/jsmiley-share/Aurora/RDS+Aurora+Connectivity+Guide+-+v4.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> both my own ip and the public ip of my EC2 instance

You should use the private IP in the security group instead of the public IP. An even better method would be to list the security group the EC2 instance belongs to, instead of its IP address.